Not able to drop non-clustered index
I was executing a query to create a non clustered index in one of the table and that has around 43M of rows. It runs more than 1 hour, then I felt something is wrong and have cancelled the query execution.
I refreshed the database and checked Indexes folder under the same table and there is no such index is created. When I try to run the same query again getting below error
The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_My_Index_name' already exists on table 'My_Table_Name'
When I try to drop the same index again getting below error
cannot drop the index 'IX_My_Index_name' because it does not exist or you do not have permission
Any suggestions what could have gone wrong here

Do you get any result from select * from sys.index_resumable_operations also select * from sys.indexes where name = 'IX_My_Index_name' and object_id = OBJECT_ID('My_Table_Name')

Also check sys.stats fot that name.

@Charlieface both queries returns no records

@TiborKaraszi no records in sys.stats too

Try DBCC CHECKDB (yourdb) WITH (NO_INFOMSGS, EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS )
